# Webpack module not Found Error while running 'yarn watch' in Apollo client project

Tags: ethereum, react-apollo, truffle

When I am trying to run the project in development mode I am getting this Error :
webpack-for-webDll ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'truffle' in '/home/...'

Comment: The issue is resolved. It occurred because of the spinjs version change.This is somehow related to https://github.com/npm/registry/issues/255 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. It occurred because of the spinjs version change (some dependency node modules deleted while updated to higher version).
This is somehow related to [this](http://github.com/npm/registry/issues/255)